# How to apply videogravity in GPUImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, avfoundation, gpuimage

I want to display AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288 video in a 320x320 UIView and with AVCapturePreivewLayer I was able to set the video gravity like this

```
[captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
```

Is there a way in GPUImage to do this or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a too late to help you, but maybe I can help someone else with the same problem.

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to set the fill mode of your `GPUImageView` to `kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill`

Like:

```
cameraView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill
```